# Asp.net Facebook Login

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-identity

I am trying to link a local account with facebook and then be able to retrieve the account's facebook uploaded photos and show them on the site.

I have created the local account and i have linked it through the /Manage endpoint with Facebook. So now in the ApplicationUserLogins table there is an entry with the local user id and the Facebook provider key.

Is it possible that when the user logins to the site using his username and password to be able to show his uploaded photos from Facebook?

Right now i am using the FB api but it seems that it always gets the logged in user from Facebook instead of the FB linked account.

The relevant part on how i am retrieving the photos is this:

```
FB.api(
    '/me/photos',
    'GET',
    { "type": "uploaded", "fields": "from,link,name,width,height,picture" },
function (response){....})
```

Is this even possible to "auto login" the user to FB when he has previously linked their local accounts with FB?

Comment: `/me` points to who/whatever the access token belongs to. But if you want to read photos of other users, then you should not do this client-side - exposing someone else’s access token in client-side code is a big no-no. So if anything, you should port this to the server side - and there, implement proper caching as well, because if you fire those requests on every profile page load, you would run into the API rate limits quite quickly.

Comment: @CBroe well.... in my mind (i know i may be WAY too wrong) when i am linking my local account with my facebook account i should probably be able to access my photos even when i choose not to login with facebook but using my username and password instead. Or else what is the point of linking the accounts? I do not mind if i have to do it server side, but currently i really do not know where to go next or what to read even in order to fiund an answer.

Comment: You need a valid user access token. To get one, you must send the user through the Facebook login flow - but that does not mean that they have to actively “log in” every single time; if a user used an app before and granted the permissions it asked for, then they will not get asked a second time, but this will all be handled silently in the background.

Comment: @CBroe so, should i redirect them after loging in using their username and password to the various linked providers? For insatnce, what would the flow be? User logs in with u/p then the system picks up their linked providers and one by one redirectes them to them in order to get the tokens?

Comment: Excuse my social media illiteracy....

Comment: Depends, and different networks might handle things differently. Facebook user tokens can be extended to be valid for up to 60 days for example, so that is rather the way you want to go there, than requesting a new token on every visit.

Comment: So if a user has linked with several providers, should he be redirected to all (even if unnoticed) in order to get fresh tokens? This really sounds kind of weird to be honest....

Comment: It needs a connection to the provider's servers, because that is how OAuth works. Doesn't have to be a redirect necessarily, f.e. with Facebook, the JS SDK can determine that kind of stuff in the background. (Requires that you show the user at least one page that has it embedded first of course, so that way you can't know up front with their first visit.)